# Разница между объектными файлами между языками C и C++

Tags: c++, c, lib, obj

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли отличия между объектными (obj) файлами и файлами статических библиотек (lib) между языками C и C++?

Если отличия есть, то насколько они велики?

Comment: от компилятора должно зависеть

Comment: и конечно ещё манглинг имен.

Comment: ABI документ читайте га конкретную архитектуру, а поверх -- на соответствующий toolchain.

Comment: Если использовать компиляторы одной и той же фирмы (допустим, Microsoft), то формат будет один и тот же, но именование функций внутри итогового файла будет различным (из-за манглинга имен).